# Detect process abort

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

i'm running some c++ binary application from python using `subprocess.Popen`. How can I handle aborting of this process? For example, my c++ breaks with assertion and I see in console:

```
binary: /usr/include/.../file.hpp:42: Assertion `min <= max' failed.
Aborted
```

Process closes but how to catch this in python using popen handle?

Comment: Do you want to detect the end of a process or to catch the output in console?

Comment: @luc detect the end of process. `handle.wait()` doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have called `handle = subprocess.Popen(...)`, you will have to call, at some point, [`handle.wait()`. Its return value](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), which is at the same time the `returncode` attribute of the process handle object, shows if the process has completed normally (with a value >= 0) or if it has died due to a signal (with a value < 0).

Example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("kill -ABRT $$", shell=True)
-6
>>> a = subprocess.Popen("kill -ABRT $$", shell=True)
>>> a.wait()
-6
>>> subprocess.call("kill -SEGV $$", shell=True)
-11
```

With a C program looking like

```
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    assert(0);
}
```

I can do

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["./ass"])
ass: ass.c:4: main: Assertion `0' failed.
-6
```

so I have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `SIGABRT` signal. However, remember that it might not be possible to continue after the signal handler is finished without further crashes.

I do recommend that you try to fix whatever is causing the assert to fail though.

Comment: @Ockonal See e.g. the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module. However it indicates something wrong in your code, I really suggest you fix it instead of working around it.

Comment: That module is used for catching sigabort in python script, not in own process? For now I can't fix it because it fails due to another library in big project.